# wsgi.input from request.meta

Tags: django, wsgi

I'm upgrading to Django 1.8, and in one of my views I need to accept a parameter from the client that is set in the header.

In django 1.3 it was accessible by it's name, i.e:

```
{'HTTP_NAME_OF_PARAM':'value of parameter'}
```

And all was fine. However now, the header seems to look like this:

```
{'wsgi.input': <socket._fileobject object at 0x10ce09a50>}
```

So I need to get the data from this socket._fileobject in the header. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that has not changed. Please show the actual code that is trying to get this value; how are you accessing the "header" at all?

Comment: I found this in the docs:

Answer (score 0):

I shoud've mentioned that I use runserver for now, so I found this in the docs:

Note that runserver strips all headers with underscores in the name, so you won’t see them in META. This prevents header-spoofing based on ambiguity between underscores and dashes both being normalizing to underscores in WSGI environment variables. It matches the behavior of Web servers like Nginx and Apache 2.4+.

When changing the name to NAME-OF-PARAM it worked :)